# To find count of current employees in power bi using dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-cleaning, data-modeling, data-transform

i have a employee table like this.

[emp table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOAOL.png)

My requirement is to count current employees in the orgnisation using dax.
In the above table for employee id 1001 there were 3 rows of the data(i.e whenever there is change in salary a new row has been updated), but he left the company on 3-8-2023 .
But when i count the no of current employess since in first two rows his status is mentioned as active his id is also been counted. so that instead of getting the count as 2 i am getting result as 3 as the dax is counting the first rows since the status is active.

I tried by count rows using count fnction and applying filter as status = "active"

I want answer for how to handle such type of scenarios in rela time and what is the solution for above thing.
Thanking you.

Comment: Count distinct of total employees minus count distinct of employees that have left?

Comment: Please add the table directly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to just count distinct IDs and subtract IDs that have left, as suggested by @PhobosFerro:

```
Current Employees =
VAR _all =
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Employee id] )
VAR _resigned =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Employee id] ),
        'Table'[status] = "Resigned"
    )
RETURN
    _all - _resigned
```

You can also do a `SUMX` over a summarized table, but I think this solution will be slower:

```
Current Employees  = 
SUMX ( 
    SUMMARIZE ( 
        'Table' , 
        'Table'[Employee id] ,
        "LeaveDate" , MAX ( 'Table'[leave date] )
    ),
    IF ( ISBLANK ( [LeaveDate] ) , 1 )
)
```